# ui5 command in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, sap-fiori

Am trying to use ui5 command in visual studio code but unfortunately it is giving below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXOb7.png)

I observed few things may be node js version need to be updated but unfortunately when I checked the version node js in command prompt showing below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ6b6.png)

but in help command showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRoIO.png)

Is the ui5 commands are due to this conflict or any other thing. How we can resolve this so that ui5 commands will work in visual studio code

ui5 commands should work in visual studio code

Comment: Hi, welcome. The use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you